# best format for saving a link to a web-page

Tags: android, android-webview, android-file

What is the best format of saving a link to a web page?

I want it to get saved so that I could display the link (or a file that represent the link) in my app and could later display the actual page in the WebView.

I've tried creating an URL file but it seems there no predefined programs for opening this file format.

P.S. I need this format to be recognized by the default browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the appropriate format - solved the problem by saving the link to a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion SharedPreference is the best way.